# Is it possible to add a @Html.textboxfor for a selected item in a @Html.dropdownlistfor, dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of chemicals and need to be able to have the user select one or more chemicals and enter a value for each chemical selected, dynamically. What are some ways I can accomplish this? I am using asp.net and MVC 4 with c#.

Comment: Refer the ansers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options

Comment: Front end frameworks such as Knockout.js could very easily do this, it's a front end javascript framework that implements the MVVM pattern, the tool for the job :) although MVC is a presentation layer design  pattern, it's strength lies more in the delivery of the data to the front end, MVVM is much more  presentation focused, combine the two